# CString used on static method

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am stuck into a problem, and I will be very grateful if you help me.

I have a MDI, and in CDocument class, I have a struct:

CMyDoc.h

```
class CMyDoc : public CDocument
{
...

struct SRecord
{
    SRecord(){}
    virtual ~SRecord(){}
    CString sName;
    CString sState;
    CString sDateu;
    CString sDatec;
};

CTypedPtrArray<CPtrArray, SRecord*> m_arrRecord;
```

and somewhere I load this struct with data:

```
    SRecord* pItem = new SRecord;
    pItem->sName        = saItem.GetAt(ML_ASSETNAME);
    pItem->sState       = saItem.GetAt(ML_STATE);
    pItem->sDateu       = saItem.GetAt(ML_DATEU;
    pItem->sDatec       = saItem.GetAt(ML_DATEC);
    m_arrRecord.Add(pItem);
```

ok. I am trying to sort data:

```
void CMyDoc::SortData(int nColumn, BOOL bAscending)
{
switch(nColumn)
{
case 9:
    if(bAscending)qsort((void*)m_arrRecord.GetData(), m_arrRecord.GetSize(), sizeof(SRecord), CompareDateUAscending);
    else qsort((void*)m_arrRecord.GetData(), m_arrRecord.GetSize(), sizeof(SRecord), CompareDateUDescending);
    break;
...
}
```

but the *problem* become when data is access in static method:

```
int CMyDoc::CompareDateUDescending(const void* arg1, const void* arg2)
{
SRecord* Record1 = (SRecord*)arg1;
SRecord* Record2 = (SRecord*)arg2;

if(Record1->sDateu.IsEmpty() || Record2->sDateu.IsEmpty()) // <--- crash !
    return 0;

COleDateTime dL, dR;
dL.ParseDateTime(Record1->sDateu);
dR.ParseDateTime(Record2->sDateu);

return (dL == dR ? 0 : (dL < dR ? 1 : -1));
}
```

and the crash take me here (**atlsimpstr.h**):

```
CStringData* GetData() const throw()
{
    return( reinterpret_cast< CStringData* >( m_pszData )-1 );  // the crash lead me on this line 
}
```

what I am doing wrong ?

Any help will be very appreciated !

**Update:**

I have tried this:

```
int CMyDoc::CompareDateUDescending(const void* arg1, const void* arg2)
{
SRecord* Record1 = *(SRecord**)arg1;    // <-- OK
SRecord* Record2 = *(SRecord**)arg2;    // <-- Unhandled exception* see note below

if(Record1->sDateu.IsEmpty() || Record2->sDateu.IsEmpty())
    return 0;

COleDateTime dL, dR;
dL.ParseDateTime(Record1->sDateu);
dR.ParseDateTime(Record2->sDateu);

return (dL == dR ? 0 : (dL < dR ? 1 : -1));
}
```

and the crash told me:

"An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback." strange ...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should contain a [mcve], together with the error message. You should also describe what the code is supposed to do and in what way it fails to do so. Atm it is not clear what is the problem

Comment: Ok, I try to clarify.

Comment: One issue: `sizeof(SRecord)` should be `sizeof(SRecord *)`

Comment: @franji: Yes, that solved me the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) comparison function receives pointers *to the elements* in the array. But since the elements in the array are themselves pointers what your specific function receives as arguments are pointers to pointers to `SRecord`, i.e. `SRecord**`.

You can solve it by doing e.g.

```
const SRecord* Record1 = *reinterpret_cast<const SRecord**>(arg1);
```

That is, you cast `arg1` to `SRecord**` and then dereference that pointer to get a `SRecord*`.

---

Example on how to use the [C++ standard sort function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

First you need to update your comparison function a little:

```
// The comparison function should return true if Record1 is *smaller* than Record2,
// and return false otherwise
bool CMyDoc::CompareDateUDescending(const SRecord* Record1, const SRecord* Record2)
{
    return Record1->sDateu < Record2->sDateu;
}
```

Then to call sort:

```
std::sort(m_arrRecord.GetData(), m_arrRecord.GetData() + m_arrRecord.GetSize(), CompareDateUDescending);
```

*Much* simpler!

Comment: I have tried your code, but I get this: error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'const void *' to 'CMyDoc::SRecord **' ... I feel I am not far to solve this issue ...

Comment: @flaviu2 Ah, missed the `const` bits. Added them in my answer. I think... Something like that anyway. :)

Comment: Hmm ... after I put what you said, I get pretty same error: error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'const void *' to 'const CMyDoc::SRecord **' ... strange ...

Comment: case 9:
  if(bAscending)qsort((void*)m_arrRecord.GetData(), m_arrRecord.GetSize(), sizeof(SRecord), CompareDateUAscending);
  else qsort((void*)m_arrRecord.GetData(), m_arrRecord.GetSize(), sizeof(SRecord), CompareDateUDescending);
  break;

Comment: @flaviu2 The *call* to `qsort` is okay, it's the comparison function which is wrong. Just fiddle around with the placement of the `const` in the `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: I have tried this: const SRecord* Record1 = reinterpret_cast<const SRecord*>(arg1); ... no compilation error, but crash in the same way ... I have to dig in ...

Comment: @flaviu2 But that puts you back to the exact same problem you already have and are asking about. `arg1` and `arg2` are pointers *to pointers* to `SRecord`. Perhaps `SRecord const* Record1 = *reinterpret_cast<SRecord const**>(arg1)`? Or perhaps `SRecord* const*`?

Comment: I have tried this, but not worked ... I will be back with code to show you what I have tried.

Comment: @flaviu2 Ah screw it, I really wanted to use a "proper" cast as I really dislike C-style casting in C++. Just do `SRecord* Record1 = *(SRecord**) arg1;` The cast to pointer to pointer, and the dereference are the important bits.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude: kindly thank you for all your posts, it is almost done, seem to be ok now, except when I am trying to get Record2 pointer, I get a crash ... but there could be another problem, I don't know yet. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @flaviu2 Good that you start to get a hold of it. Then I should bring you down a little by telling you about [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) which is the standard C++ sort function and it is *type safe* so you don't have to deal with the weird pointers and the type-uncertainty. Using [standard C++ algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) is the preferred solution over the type-unsafe old C functions. :)